# VBA to convert texts to numbers except formula and non-numeric texts

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a `Range("B6:T10000")`

Data in the range are a mixture of `blanks`,`#'s` ,`numbers (formatted as texts)`, `texts` and most importantly `formulas`.

Can someone please help with a VBA macro to:

- Find anything that looks like number and convert it to number
- Ignore the rest
- Don't convert formulas to values

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Converter()
    Dim rBig As Range, r As Range, v As Variant
    Set rBig = Range("B6:T10000")
    For Each r In rBig
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" And r.HasFormula = False Then
            If IsNumeric(v) Then
                r.Clear
                r.Value = v
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

This version ignores errors:

```
Sub Converter()
    Dim rBig As Range, r As Range, v As Variant
    Set rBig = Range("B6:T10000")
    For Each r In rBig
        v = r.Value
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            If v <> "" And r.HasFormula = False Then
                If IsNumeric(v) Then
                    r.Clear
                    r.Value = v
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @garys-student, I ran into a `type mismatch` error, can you help?

Comment: @garys-student, `run-time error 13` `type mismatch` error, `If v <> And r...` - Line 6

Comment: Then replace **v <>""**  with  **r.Value <>""**

Comment: @garys-student Thanks but it didn't work, https://s3.amazonaws.com/pushbullet-uploads/14742-fP5I07z4AHOa2pKywSx8TbpoPm8QWNkr/IMG_20131205_233929.jpg

Comment: @garys-student I think the problem is excel's `#N/A` error, is there a way you can add `IsError` to ignore all excel errors as well. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without code, or with quicker code avoiding loops

**Manual**

1. Copy a blank cell
2. Select your range `B6:T100001`
3. Press `F5`. Then `Goto ... Special`
4. check `Constants` and then `Text`
5. `Paste Special Multiply` and check `Add`

This converts text only cells with numbers into numbers, and leaves actual text or formulae alone

**Code**

```
Sub Update()
Dim rng1 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Range("B6:T10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
On Error Resume Next
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'presumes last cell in sheet is blank
Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Copy
rng1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

here's my version:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng as Range, cel as Range

Set rng = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6:T10000")

For Each cel In rng
    If Not IsError(cel.Value) Then _
        If Len(cel.Value) <> 0 And cel.HasFormula = False And _
            IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then cel.Value = Val(cel.Value)
Next cel

End Sub
```

I've tested it, and works fine.
Hope this helps.

Comment: opps, i didn't see that gary already posted an edited one which will work for you just fine i guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("b5:b6004,h5:h6004").Select    
For Each xCell In Selection    
If IsNumeric(xCell) = False Then    
    xCell.Value = Val(xCell.Value)    
Else    
End If    
Next xCell
```