# Convert cell to number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on creating a macro that will manipulate some data in Excel and create a report for me. The problem is that some of the provided data comes stored as text.

I'm pretty new at VB so my trick so far has been to recorded the desired action as a macro and then copy-paste that subroutine into my code. However, this doesn't seem to work in this case. What I normally do is to select the cells and then click the `!` pop-up error menu that appears and select "Convert to Number".

[image: Convert to Number dialog]

What is the VB code that I need to convert selected cells from text to numbers?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [VBA to convert texts to numbers except formula and non-numeric texts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408689/vba-to-convert-texts-to-numbers-except-formula-and-non-numeric-texts). That thread has a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT, I looked for the solution (didn't think I would be the first) but it didn't come up in any of my searches.  Maybe cause I didn't use VBA in my search query... Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: See the addendum in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920305/vba-remove-from-cell-content-in-a-range/28920651?s=3|0.9261#28920651).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys.  Using the link provided by @PeterT and modifying the solution provided by @brettdj in said link, I have managed to answer my own question.  The code I am using is:

```
Sub ConvertTextNumberToNumber(CellSelect)

Dim rng1 As Range

Sheets("Raw Data").Select

Range(CellSelect).Select
Set rng1 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Copy
rng1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
End Sub
```

I went for this code over other code provided because it was quicker, presumably because it didn't use a loop.
I don't know how good the code is but it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
Sub ConvertTextNumberToNumber()
 For Each WS In Sheets
 On Error Resume Next
 For Each r In WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
 If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = Val(r.Value)
 Next
 Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert strings to numbers in VBA:

For individual cells, use CDbl:

```
myVar = "123"  'a string
Cells("A1") = CDbl(myVar)   'converted to double.
```

For a range:

```
Range("A1:A50").NumberFormat = "0"
```

For an entire column

```
Columns(1).NumberFormat = "0"
```

For more NumberFormat options, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648149/what-are-numberformat-options-in-excel-vba).